# Como montar uma lista de objetos genéricos em C?

Tags: c, tipagem

Em muitas linguagens de mais alto nível é possível ter uma estrutura ou uma coleção de dados de tipos variados, muitas vezes usa-se o tipo `Object` para isto.

Como fazer o mesmo em C? Isto é, eu não sei os tipos que entrarão na estrutura ou *array*, pode ser qualquer que estará correto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O mais provável é usar um `void *`. Isto fará que qualquer objeto será colocado no objeto em questão (uma estrutura ou uma coleção) como referência, ou seja, será um ponteiro. Desta forma você uniformiza o tipo que terá sempre o tamanho do ponteiro.

A desvantagem é que todos os dados serão apontados. Isso pode ser ruim para os tipos que normalmente são por valor (`int`, `char`, `double`, etc.) já que haverá uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) para acessar o dado (acessa o ponteiro e depois vai onde o valor está) e além de ocupar o espaço para o objeto, é muito provável que terá que alocá-lo no *heap*. Será um erro na maior parte dos casos apenas pegar o ponteiro para o valor na *stack*. Isso funciona se ele não escapar para fora da função corrente (pode usar nas funções chamadas ali, mas não pela chamadora, estiver confuso sobre isto dê uma lisa [como a *stack* funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)).

Também tem uma outra possibilidade que pode otimizar isso, embora possa dar uma certa complexidade no código. Podemos usar uma `union` com os tipos escalares e provavelmente um `void *` para os demais. Ele ocupará sempre o espaço do maior tipo, os tipos por valor (escalares) serão usados por valor mesmo e só os tipos por referência terão a indireção, que já teria de qualquer forma.

Na verdade para ficar mais flexível provavelmente vai ocupar um espaço a mais para indicar qual é o tipo que está armazenado ali. Isto é chamado de *tagged union*.

Note que o que está fazendo é tornar C uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica. De fato é assim que a linguagens de tipagem dinâmica costumam trabalhar.

Veja nas duas execuções abaixo em máquinas diferentes que o tamanho da estrutura é diferente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    enum { is_int, is_float, is_char, is_pointer } type;
    union {
        int i;
        float f;
        char c;
        void *p;
    } value;
} Tipo;

int main(void) {
    int x = 10;
    float y = 5.5f;
    char c = 'h';
    char a[] = "teste";
    Tipo var1 = { .type = is_int, .value.i = x };
    Tipo var2 = { .type = is_float, .value.f = y };
    Tipo var3 = { .type = is_char, .value.c = c };
    Tipo var4 = { .type = is_pointer, .value.p = a };
    printf("%d\n", var1.value.i);
    printf("%f\n", var2.value.f);
    printf("%c\n", var3.value.c);
    printf("%s\n", (char *)var4.value.p);
    printf("%d\n", var2.type);
    printf("%zd\n", sizeof(var2));
    printf("%d\n", var3.type);
    printf("%zd\n", sizeof(var3));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/NtYjx5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/makqllfh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/DynamicTyping.c).

Answer (score 4):

Então - C é uma linguagem estáticamente tipada, sem suporte estático para objetos. por outro lado, ela te dá controle sorbe quase tudo o que quiser fazer, e provÊ um tipo de dados "genérico" - que é justamente o ponteiro do tipo void (void *). Quando você declara uma variável do tipo `void *`- tudo o que o compilador "sabe" é que ele é um endereço de memória - e o seu programa será o único responsável por manipular os dados naquela região de memória.

Então, não é possível ter m objeto "genérico" que use "Structs" pré-definidas em C de forma dinâmica- - você não tem como passar um tipo de struct como parâmetro para uma função.

Isso quer dizer que você terá que estruturar seus tipos de objetos de forma que eles possuam alguns campos fixos, no começo da estrutura de dados, que descrevam o layout dos dados na sessões posteriores - (inclusive o tamanho).

Por exemplo, você poderia definir, em "português" mesmo, que para seus objetos, os dois primeiros bytes serao um inteiro de 16 bits definindo o comprimento de uma string, em que cada byte corresponde a um caractére ASCII definindo um campo - tipo "B - Unisgned char, b - signed char, I 32bit unsigned integer" - "L 64 bit unsigned integer", "Z 16bit size prefixed string". 
E então você escreve funçoes que tratam dados com essa formatação conforme a descrição. Note que isso independe de você definir esse cabeçalho do objeto como um struct em si, ou simplesmente usar aritmética de ponteiros, dentro das suas funções, para alocar a memória necessária e manipular os atributos do seus objetos de forma dinâmica.

Para o tipo de objeto que eu descrevi acima, poderiamos ter essa função para criar novos objetos, alocando em tempo de execução a memória necessária:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *create_object(char *definition) {
   short unsigned int size = 2, def_len=0;
   void *new_obj=NULL;

   for (int i = 0; definition[i]; i++) {
      def_len ++;
      size += 1;
      switch (defintion[i]) {
         case 'B': size += 1; break;
         case 'I': size += 4; break;
         ...
      }
   }
   new_obj = malloc(size);
   if (!new_obj) {return NULL;}
   (short integer *)(new_obj[0]) = def_len;
   for(int i = 0; definition[i]; i++) {(char *)(new_obj[i]) = defintion[i]}
   return new_obj;
}
```

(Uma função para manipular os campos em si, dentro dessa memória reservada, teria que ir verificando cada caractere da string de definição para saber a posição de cada campo, quando fosse acessar um campo pelo seu índice numérico):

```
int get_field_offset(void *obj, int field_num, char *type) {
    int field_offset = 2 + *((short int *)obj);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < field_num; i ++) {
         char field_type = (char *)(obj[i + 2]);
         if (i >= *((short int *)obj)) {return 0;}
         switch (field_type) {
             case 'B': field_offset += 1; break;
             case 'I': field_offset += 4; break;
             ...
         }

    }
    type[0] = field_type
    return field_offset
}

void set_field_value(void *obj, int field_num, void *value) {
    char *type[1]=0;
    int offset;
    offset = get_field_offset(obj, field_num, type)
    if (!offset) return;  // field does not exist
    switch (type[0]) {
        case 'B': *(char *)(obj[offset]) = value;
        case 'I': *(int *)(obj[offset]) = value;
    }
}

void * get_field_value(void *obj, int field_num, char *type) {
    int offset;
    offset = get_field_offset(obj, field_num, type)
    if (!offset) return NULL;
    // Return the address of the  exact field, and its type indication on "type"
    return &(obj[offset]);
}
```

Então, perceba que com isso você pode manipular diferentes estruturas de dados, que mudam em tempo de execução, e nem precisa usar a palavra chave  "struct" do C. Pode até mesmo usar uma definição de objeto que venha de uma entrada de dados - seja o usuário digitando, seja lendo de um arquivo texto.

```
void *coordenadas = create_object("ff")
set_field_value(coordenadas, 0, 23.0);
set_field_value(coordenadas, 1, 45.23); 
...
```

(PAra isso, é só colocar `f` como sendo `float` ou mesmo `double` nos switch cases acima) - e você pode guardar latitude e longitude nesses objetos.

Essa é uma forma "bem crua" - e já daria bastante trabalho para acomodar tipos de dados de comprimento variável aí dentro. Mas você poderia sofisticar quanto quisesse, por exemplo, adicionando um campo para contar quantas referências existem ao objeto (dessa forma, sempre que um trecho do código não precisar mais de um objeto, diminui um do contador de referências - se esse contador chega a zero, o objeto pode ser desalocado imediatamente, liberando a memória). Outra sofisticação interessante é incluir uma tabela de strings que permitira, por exemplo, dar nomes textuais aos campos.  Claro que o código em C vai ficando proporcionalmente mais complexo.

Vários sistemas de objetos, ou protocolos de dados genéricos, são escritos em C puro, e todos eles tem que partir mais ou menos desses princípios (det er campos fixos no início dos dados que determinam o layout do objeto todo)- o framework "gobject", por exemplo, o "protobuf" do Google, o `Cap'n'Proto` e  a própria linguagem de programação Python - da qual, todos os objetos tem uma representação em memória que pode ser usada a partir da linguagem C feitos bem nesses termos. (Em geral, esses campos iniciais que definem o layout de um objeto não são visíveis se você acessa o objeto a partir de código Python, mas estão lá se você acessa os objetos a partir de C). A definição dos objetos em Python tem que ser incluida em qualquer extenção em Cque vá manipualr objetos Python, por exemplo, e para poder manipular objetos genéricos, ela usa os tipos (typedefs) definidos no arquivo [object.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h) - veja esse arquivo, perto da linha 112.

Comment: Muito bom, se não aparecer nenhuma melhor, essa será aceita ;)