# Polimorfismo em C

Tags: c, polimorfismo

É possível usar *Polimorfismo* em uma linguagem estruturada como o **C**?

Linguagens como `c++`,`Java`,`etc`(Linguagens orientadas a objetos), possuem estruturas capazes de herdar funcionalidades para reaproveitamento de código(Um dos motivos), mas em C, é possível usar essas técnicas de programação?

Comment: Relacionada, não sei se é dup [Polimorfismo em linguagem procedural](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/14262)

Comment: Escrevi extensamente sonre um assunto relacionado antes de ontem, aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180783/como-montar-uma-lista-de-objetos-gen%C3%A9ricos-em-c/181019#181019

Comment: acho que é possível, mas tenho certeza que não vale a pena

Comment: sei que já está respondida, mas só pra comentar: teria que testar isso com um compilador C "puro" (http://www.cpm.z80.de/small_c.html), e não com um compilador C/C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma de "polimorfismo" muito usada em programas C é usando ponteiros de função, como já comentaram. Você encontrará esse tipo de implementação no kernel do Linux, na OpenSSL, etc.

Veja um exemplo. Declarei vários animais diferentes e cada um emite o som apropriado a ele. Bastou definir o comportamento correto de cada um na inicialização.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// ponteiro para função de emitir som
typedef void (*func_emitir_som)(void);

// tipo genérico
typedef struct {
  func_emitir_som soar;
} Animal;

void latir(void) {
  puts("au! au!");
}

void miar(void) {
  puts("miau! miau!");
}

void mugir(void) {
  puts("muuu! muuu!");
}

int main(void) {
  Animal vaca     = { &mugir };
  Animal cachorro = { &latir };
  Animal gato     = { &miar  };

  vaca.soar();     // a vaca muge
  cachorro.soar(); // o cachorro late
  gato.soar();     // o gato mia

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sim. Você será o responsável pela implementação. Existem bibliotecas prontas como http://ooc-coding.sourceforge.net. Recomendo utilizar C++, se possível.

É possível criar uma `struct` para representar a classe, com ponteiros de funções para acessar as variáveis desta classe. Para cada função, inclua o parâmetro `this`, com o mesmo tipo da `struct`. Para a construção da classe, crie uma função que devolve por parâmetro o objeto e, nesta função, inicialize as respectivas funções já declaradas as variáveis da `struct`. Estas funções podem ser reatribuidas em tempo de execução (eu acho muito legal essa possibilidade).

Para herança, crie uma variável na `struct` com o tipo da classe herdada (ou um `array` para múltipla herança).

Para encapsulamento crie um *ponteiro opaco* para a `struct`.

No entanto, essa prática é muito trabalhosa e o aproveitamento talvez não seja conseguido, dependendo da complexidade do código. Recomendo utilizar funções em módulos separados, tratando `structs` como se fossem objetos, sem criar ponteiros de funções na struct (essa prática só aumenta a complexidade do código e dificulta a solução de *bugs*), resolvendo as interfaces, quando necessário.

Answer (score 0):

Pode-se simular herança simples em C com muita facilidade. No entanto, isso depende de efetuar coerções de tipo (*typecasts*), o que te impede de usar o sistema de tipos para pegar alguns *bugs* simples. Vejamos um exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ANOS 31556952 /* segundos por ano */
#define MKOBJ(obj) do { obj = malloc(sizeof(obj[0])); if (!obj) exit(1); } while (0)
#define RMOBJ(obj) (free(obj), obj = NULL)

/* Estrutura base */
typedef struct pessoa_t {
    char * nome;
    time_t dt_nascimento;
    unsigned char sexo;
} pessoa_t;

/* Estrutura derivada */
typedef struct empregado_t {
    pessoa_t base; /* NÃO é um ponteiro */
    unsigned int matricula;
    time_t dt_admissao;
} empregado_t;

void
imprimir_pessoa(pessoa_t * p) {
    printf("%s é %s de %d anos de idade.\n",
           p->nome,
           p->sexo == 'F' ? "uma moça" : "um rapaz",
           (time(NULL) - p->dt_nascimento) / ANOS
    );
}

void
imprimir_empregado(empregado_t * e) {
    imprimir_pessoa((pessoa_t *) e);
    printf("%s entrou na empresa há %d anos.\n",
           ((pessoa_t *) e)->sexo == 'F' ? "Ela" : "Ele",
           (time(NULL) - e->dt_admissao) / ANOS
    );
}

static void
criar_pessoa_aux(pessoa_t * self,
                 const char * nome,
                 char sexo,
                 int dia_nasc,
                 int mes_nasc,
                 int ano_nasc) {
    static struct tm tm;

    self->nome = strdup(nome);
    self->sexo = sexo;
    tm.tm_mday = dia_nasc;
    tm.tm_mon = mes_nasc - 1;
    tm.tm_year = ano_nasc - 1900;
    self->dt_nascimento = mktime(&tm);
}

pessoa_t *
criar_pessoa(const char * nome,
             char sexo,
             int dia_nasc,
             int mes_nasc,
             int ano_nasc) {
    pessoa_t * result;

    MKOBJ(result);
    criar_pessoa_aux(result, nome, sexo, dia_nasc, mes_nasc, ano_nasc);

    return result;
}

void
destruir_pessoa(pessoa_t * p) {
    RMOBJ(p->nome);
    RMOBJ(p);
}

empregado_t *
criar_empregado(const char * nome,
                char sexo,
                int dia_nasc,
                int mes_nasc,
                int ano_nasc,
                int matricula,
                int dia_adm,
                int mes_adm,
                int ano_adm) {
    empregado_t * result;
    static struct tm tm;

    MKOBJ(result);
    criar_pessoa_aux((pessoa_t *) result, nome, sexo, dia_nasc, mes_nasc, ano_nasc);
    result->matricula = matricula;
    tm.tm_mday = dia_adm;
    tm.tm_mon = mes_adm - 1;
    tm.tm_year = ano_adm - 1900;
    result->dt_admissao = mktime(&tm);

    return result;
}

void
destruir_empregado(empregado_t * e) {
    pessoa_t * p = (pessoa_t *) e;
    RMOBJ(p->nome);
    RMOBJ(e);
}

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    pessoa_t * Alice;
    empregado_t * Beto, * Carol;

    /*                      -------nome------- sexo -nascimento-- -matr- ---admissão-- */
    Alice = criar_pessoa   ("Alice da Silva"  , 'F',  6, 12, 1999);
    Beto  = criar_empregado("Beto da Costa"   , 'M',  1,  5, 1974, 11111,  1,  1, 2007);
    Carol = criar_empregado("Carol dos Santos", 'F',  9,  3, 1990, 22222,  1, 10, 2015);

    imprimir_pessoa(Alice);
    imprimir_pessoa((pessoa_t *) Beto);
    imprimir_pessoa((pessoa_t *) Carol);
    puts("----------\n");
    // imprimir_empregado((empregado_t *) Alice); /* SEGFAULT! */
    imprimir_empregado(Beto);
    imprimir_empregado(Carol);

    return 0;
}
```

Como se pode ver, dá um bocado de trabalho: os construtores têm que alocar automaticamente as variáveis e tratar os erros de alocação, e depois inicializá-las; os destrutores têm que apagar as *strings* alocadas e depois apagar a si mesmas, etc. Naturalmente, isto será o caso para qualquer arquitetura que não seja própria da linguagem.

Dito isto, você pode ver como o `empregado_t *`, passado para uma função que espera um `pessoa_t *`, faz a coisa certa e funciona perfeitamente bem já que o primeiro elemento da `empregado_t` é uma estrutura `pessoa_t`. Quando se faz o *cast*, o empregado continua a ser uma pessoa válida.

Por outro lado, como você está fazendo coerção de tipos, o compilador não te impede de forçar uma função que recebe um `empregado_t *` a receber uma `pessoa_t *` que não seja um `empregado_t *`. Neste caso, você só vai ver o erro em execução (com sorte; a coerção pode simplesmente acessar dados de outro objeto como se fossem os campos faltantes, e ele silenciosamente continuar rodando com dados inconsistentes).

Como tudo o mais em C, é uma técnica válida, mas o programador tem que se responsabilizar pelos *casts* que faz.

Comment: A pergunta fala em polimorfismo e não herança.

Comment: @bigown: Meu entendimento é que herança é um mecanismo para implementar polimorfismo. Se não é, em que diferem?

Comment: São mecanismos diferentes. De fato a herança permite aplicar o polimorfismo se subtipo facilmente, só isso. O seu código não faz polimorfismo, nem avaliei se faz herança de fato, me parece que nem isso foi feito. Algumas coisas que podem ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154421/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89309/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158579/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151243/101 esse mostra a substituição de comportamento sem polimorfismo.

Comment: Tudo o que foi feito aí é manual. O que você está achando que é herança na verdade é só composição. É óbvio que C não permite que tudo seja feito transparentemente, mas pelo menos precisar ser automático.