# Struct com union está dando erro de uso inválido

Tags: c++, struct, union

Preciso usar uma `union` dentro de uma `struct`, mas não estou conseguindo. O erro apresentado é

> [Error] invalid use of 'union Cliente::documento'

Struct:

```
struct Cliente{
       string nome, email;
       union documento{
             long cpf,cnpj;
       };
};
```

Função:

```
void cadastrarCliente(Cliente *cli){
     fstream aCliente;
     aCliente.open("clientes.txt", ios::out|ios::app); 
     aCliente << cli->documento << " " << 
                 cli->nome << " " << 
                 cli->email << "\n";
     aCliente.close();         
}
```

Comment: O que te faz concluir que `Cliente::documento` é um membro de dado e não uma definição de `union`?

Comment: Oi Mário! Minha dúvida está basicamente nisso. Eu fiz uma validação antes mas apresentou o mesmo erro: cli->documento.cpf ou cli->documento->cpf ou cli->documento::cpf deram o mesmo erro. Comecei a ver essa linguagem esse semestre, e ainda tenho algumas dúvidas (essa em específico não encontrei exemplos em lugar algum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, não parece precisar de uma `union`. [CNPJ e CPF são dados descritivos e devem ser *strings* e não números](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101), o que já mata a necessidade união.

`union` com dois campos do mesmo tipo não faz muito sentido. Só para usar um nome diferente? Não vejo vantagem em C. Em C++ tem mecanismos melhores. De qualquer forma nem é o que precisa.

Uma `union` sem *tag*, uma das críticas que se faz ao mecanismo do C, não serve pra muita coisa, por isso C++ tem estruturas melhores que `union` na biblioteca, se fosse necessário. Mas claro que sempre pode usar uma *tag* extra própria na própria `struct` para saber o que pegar em cada caso, só tem o problema que isto é uma vazamento de abstração.

`union` foi criada para solucionar questões de nível mais baixo, me parece que está misturando níveis diferentes de abstração.

Por tudo isso eu prefiro nem tentar resolver seu problema específico e resolver o problema real que é mais amplo. Resolver o problema da pergunta é um paliativo que ainda manterá errado no conceito geral.

Se fizer certo só terá o espaço para a *string* do CNPJ que é maior, e claro, uma *tag* extra que me parece fundamental de qualquer forma nesse cadastro. Esse é um caso que colocar a *string inline* na `struct` parece adequado.

Questiono fortemente se deveria usar uma `struct` para um `Cliente`. Mas ok, é só um início, e tecnicamente mudará pouco usar para uma classe, apenas dará uma semântica mais adequada, e indicará mais que este provavelmente deveria ser um tipo por referência. Mas não vou insistir nisso porque nesse momento é um código simples demais.

Assim seria uma solução melhor:

```
struct Cliente {
    string nome, email, tipo, documento;
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/SimpleRecord.c).

Tem outras questões que provavelmente indicam que o código está misturando C com C++ e é a forma do século passado de fazer em C++.

Comment: Vlw pela atenção, Maniero. Sei que union é algo defasado e pretendo nunca mais usar, mas é que trata-se de um exercício da faculdade. Assim, como eu realmente preciso usar o union, não dá para usar string.

Comment: Então use em algo que precisa de `union`, não é esse caso, usar onde não precisa eu já considero um exercício errado. Ache um problema que precise de `union`, esse não precisa. Eu não vou ensinar ninguém fazer algo errado. Se algum professor mandou fazer errado, lamento, e até espero que outra pessoa te dê uma resposta, mas eu não colaboro com o erro. Mesmo que use, ainda citei vários outros erros, inclusive relacionado à `union`. O que eu posso fazer é te passar algumas coisas que respondi para você ver que a união está completamente errada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137393/101e ...

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180783/101

Comment: Grato pela atenção.